# Mellin Transform

Tags: harmonic-numbers, mellin-transform

If 
$$
H(x)=\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n}
$$
what is its Mellin transform?  I was able to find the Mellin transform of $\log(x+1)$ and of $\frac{1}{x+1}$, but I'm quite a bit inexperienced so I haven't been able to deduce the result.  I've also seen results of more general functions, but I'm having trouble interpreting all the notation.

Note: this is not a homework or test problem, but merely a curiousity.

---

Ok I'm going to put an attempt at a solution based on @robjohn 's suggestions.  Using the identity he provided, we have

$$
\int_0^{\infty} H(x) x^{s-1} dx=\int_0^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^s}{k(k+x)} dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^s}{k(k+x)} dx=
$$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{s-1}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^s}{1+y} dy=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{s-1}\pi \csc(\pi(s+1))=-\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}\zeta(1-s)
$$

Does this seem correct?  I feel like this is wrong.

Comment: It might help to write $$\begin{align}H(x) &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+x}\right)\\ &=x\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+x)}\end{align}$$

Comment: @robjohn I'm sorry, the techniques are very unfamiliar to me.  I'm trying to look up tables to use your identity, but I'm having trouble knowing what to use.  I've never formally studied any form of transform, besides a mild introduction to Fourier transforms when I took PDE.

Comment: If you know how to compute the Mellin Transform of $\frac1{1+x}$, then you should be able to compute the Mellin Transform of each summand, then add. It works out pretty nicely.

Comment: Note that $$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{x}{k(k+x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=k^{s-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^s}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: If you show more work in your question, I can post a complete answer, if you can't complete this from the hints above.

Comment: @robjohn Ok I think I solved it, but it feels wrong.

Comment: Your answer is correct. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn What about this solution?  $$ \int_0^{\infty} H(x) x^{s-1} dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_n^{\infty} x^{s-1} dx=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{sn} n^s=-\frac{\zeta(1-s)}{s}$$

Comment: It depends on how you want to define the Harmonic numbers for non-integer values. The extension I gave is a meromorphic extension. The one used in your comment above extends $H_{n+x}=H_n$ for $0\le x\lt1$, which is a step function extension.

Comment: That is the answer I got. It is correct for this extension of the Harmonic numbers. For this extension, we have $$H(x)=\gamma+\psi(x+1)$$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and $\psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).